# Uploading data from Android App to desktop program

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm pretty new to android so apologies if I'm missing an obvious solution, I'm developing an android app that would be used to record various data including photographs and hopefully the intention would be for this collected data to be uploaded to a desktop application where certain desktop specific jobs could be carried out.

Due to the fact I intend to save photographs within the app in the SQLite database as a bytearray which recorded information would be I think that it would be too data intensive to send to a server, plus I wouldn't want the desktop app to necessarily be on a server, it should be standalone. I'd prefer to use the USB connection and allow a USB upload of the data from the app sqlite db direct to the database on the pc, probably sql server. What would be the best way to approach this? Could the android ADB be used to acheive this?

Any help or suggestions on this would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Do you got ans of your posted question? I am facing same problem. I need to send My Scanned data to Desktop having MSSQL server over USB cable only.

Comment: Sorry Sk17, I never got the feature working as described above but some of the comments below look very promising, it may be something I come back to.

Comment: oh...I did work around..I scanned each QR code I need.. made arraylist out of it and mailed it to specific email address. then created desktop application such that it will check and fetch contents from new email and stored data to DB as required.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your sqllite database (as well as photos contained there) will be stored on the SD card of the device. You have to options here, first, when your desktop applications find the folder on the device SD card (should be mounted on the filesystem after connecting the device to your PC), second is to use bluetooth and initialize the transfer from the device to your desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

You could try having them on the same network and having them interact that way. I know applications such as RemoteDroid do this, but I have no experience doing so myself. There is also the fact that there is the data saved on the sd card / by putting your device in Storage mode and you could just point your desktop to the device drive and assume a designated folder your app uses exists.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the answers here, you could save your photos as files in your sd card and transfer it to your pc from there.
[Here is a dev guide on storing files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).
Another way is to transfer over WiFi. Ice cream sandwich seems to have a WiFi Direct api that allows us to perform P2P transfers over WiFi. I have not used it yet but have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/wifip2p.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

I would probably use rsync between my desktop and android. This way you can export data from your sqlite to a flat file and import it to your local database on your desktop. This way you can also put your schema into a file.

RSync is a very stable protocol to exchange files.

**Solution 2**

You can also use Amazon S3 for this purpose. The file name can contain the version number for ensuring that you have the latest file.